# Get-ADDomain fails, UI works

Tags: powershell, active-directory

Trying to join a *Windows Server 2016* to a domain using PowerShell.

However, PowerShell fails on `Get-ADDomain` with :

```
Get-ADDomain -Identity customer.com.au -Credential $domainCred
```

Error :

> Get-ADDomain : Unable to contact the server. This may be because this
>   server does not exist, it is currently down, or  it does not have the
>   Active Directory Web Services running. At line:1 char:1
>   + Get-ADDomain -Identity customer.com.au -Credential $domainCred
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (customer.com.au:ADDomain) [Get-ADDomain], ADServerDownException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryServer:0,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADDomain

```
Get-ADDomainController -Discover -Service ADWS -DomainName customer.com.au


Domain      : customer.com.au
Forest      : customer.com.au
HostName    : {CUSTOMERSVRDC06.customer.com.au}
IPv4Address : 10.20.104.86
IPv6Address : 
Name        : CUSTOMERSVRDC06
Site        : customer-main-site
```

So, AD Web Services are running on a server in that domain. I can resolve the domain.
And I can even promote this server manually via Server Manager just fine, with the same credentials.

Anybody got an idea what’s wrong with AD PowerShell?

Cheers
David

Comment: From https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd772723(v=ws.10).aspx ADWS uses port 9389 and SOAP traffic. Is there a firewall rule in place to prevent it?

Comment: Test-NetConnection says 9389 is open.

Comment: You can ping the DC?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out there was a port still missing on the network side.
They opened up the firewall for now and it works. I suspect a random high port.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you cannot reach the ADWS. That is common with corporate networks if firewall or policies are not designed to allow it. Regardless, you can achieve this with below options too.

1. Use the `-Server` param on Get-AD~ Cmdlets and specify a DC to query. You said you know at least 1 DC with ADWS on and reachable.
2. Use `Invoke-Command` or other PSRemoting features to remote into a DC and run those commands as if you were logged on locally on the DC. Doesn't need ADWS to be available on the Network.
3. You can also use PSexec with `Invoke-Expression` to run your code on the target machine.

Comment: I can actually get it to "sort of" working by using 

$splatArgs = @{
  NoGlobalCatalog = $false
  CreateDnsDelegation = $false
  Credential = $domainCred
  CriticalReplicationOnly = $false
  DatabasePath = "C:\NTDS"
  DomainName = $domainName
  InstallDns = $true
  LogPath = "C:\NTDS"
  NoRebootOnCompletion = $false
  SiteName = "customer-main-site"
  SysvolPath = "C:\SYSVOL"
  SafeModeAdministratorPassword = $secpasswd
  Force = $true
}
Install-ADDSDomainController @splatArgs

It just hangs on creating the NTDS object, but does all the rest. UI still works.